# Opinions on database design of a Document table with multiple behavior

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

A `Document` is an structure that holds all information about a transaction between an `origin` and a `destination`. Both the `origin` and `destination` can be of two types, a `company` or a `person`. What is the best approach to model an use case like this?

Idea nº 1:

```
Document
**document_columns**
origin_id -> foreign key
origin_type -> customer or person
destination_id -> foreign key
destination_type -> customer or person
```

Idea nº 2:

```
Document
**document_columns**

DocumentOrigin
document_id
origin_id
origin_type

DocumentDestination
document_id
destination_id
destination_type
```

Idea nº 3:

```
DocumentCompany
**document_columns**
company_id

DocumentPerson
**document_columns**
person_id
```

Things that could possibly affect choosing one over another is the need for reports that gather all `Documents` as if they were the same. Using `UNION` or other more advanced SQL commands to generate information about the schema should be considered too.

Comment: Is a origin type dependent on the origin or the document transaction? If it's dependent on the origin, don't put it in the document transaction

Comment: I would suggest creating person and company tables with a 1:1 relationship to a base table, and then use foreign keys from document to this table. that would make the origin/destination type column redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you already have a company and a person table. You could create an actor table, which would have a CompanyID and a PersonID foreign key, if it is a person, then PersonID would have a value, otherwise it would be null. If it is a company, then CompanyID would have a value, otherwise it would be null. So, you would have Actor(ID, CompanyID, PersonID, ...), Company(CompanyID, ...), Person(PersonID, ...) and Document(DocumentID, OriginID, DestinationID), where both OriginID and DestinationID would be foreign keys to the Actor table, where OriginID would reference the origin person/company and DestinationID would reference the destination person/company.

Comment: That would make for a lot of `LEFT JOINS` no? If i want to get the name of the origin or destination. See the gist: https://gist.github.com/murparreira/c2c3f8780c138cefefab223e500b60ab

Comment: @MurifoX when you know whether it is a company or a person, you can reduce the number of left joins. When you do not know that in advance, you will need to do so. Common fields should be stored in the Actor table, so if you do not need anything Company or Person specific, then you can do without the joins as well.